# How to get Redis key hit count?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there way to get all the keys stored in a database with their hit counts?

I want to sort the keys by their hit counts.

Comment: Please expand your question.  What kind of database?  What sort of table structure?

Comment: It's redis database. I'm storing key-value pair.

Answer (score 4):

As of v4.0.1, Redis doesn't offer this capability. If you need it in order to free up space by removing unused keys, you should perhaps consider using Redis' expiry mechanisms for that.

There are a couple of approaches you can try to get close to what you want:

- Run [`MONITOR`](https://redis.io/commands/monitor), parse the output and make your own statistics. Beware, however, of the command's impact on performance in production environments.
- Activate an LFU eviction policy (new in v4, can be set to `volatile-lfu` if you don't use expiry), and then [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) following by calling [`OBJECT freq`](https://redis.io/commands/object) on each key.

That said, there is a current effort in the pipes (https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4473) to improve the detection of hot keys when using LFU.

UPDATE: redis-cli has been added with the `--hotkeys` mode that operates as described in the 2nd bullet.

Comment: Regarding `SCAN`, do I need to store all keys in memory and sort them in my own code, or can Redis do that for me? I need a command that does something like "Get the top 1000 keys sorted by hit count descending".

Comment: Also, check out redis-cli's `--hotkeys` mode.